# Unable to create DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-code

```
Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time
```

[VSCode] I have an ASP.NET mvc project and a Data project for EntityFramework. First time using EntityFramework and VSCode.

The sln builds, but I can't run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`, because of the error above. Can't run it from the MVC folder of course.

launch.json as I found in other answers, might be the problem, I have no idea how to set it up (MVC is PMR.Web, data is PMR.Data):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/PMR.Web/bin/Debug/net5.0/PMR.Web.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/PMR.Web",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Solution Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkBP5.png)

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PMR.Data;

namespace PMR.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.RegisterDataServices(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to run Create once which produces a mapping file between the database and the c# classes.  Do you have a mapping file.  Error may indicate the mapping already exists.   Normally you can create the mapping file from VS menu by adding a new Data Source and browsing to your database.  Then VS will create the mapping file and you do not need to create the mapping in c#.  The mapping file take the database and creates a model (c# classes, dbContect).  Looks like you have a model.  Did you modify either the database or model and did not refresh the mapping?

Comment: I followed this tutorial and I'm using VSCode: https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-multi-project-net-core-database-solution-a69decdf8d7e. `dotnet ef database update` shows same error

Comment: Can you post your startup file pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this before, and the solution was to specify the startup project. In your case, if you're running the command within the PMR.Data directory:

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --startup-project ../PMR.Web/PMR.Web.csproj`

Comment: I get `Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project.`, with both projects set

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the answer. The option should be `startup-project` and not just `project`.

Comment: AH, makes sense. Solved